# Formula for conditional expectation. Related to the Fundamental Theorems of Asset Pricing

Tags: mathematics, asset-pricing, finance-mathematics, financial-engineering

> Let $\lambda$ be a probability measure on $\Omega$ (finite), with filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$. Define $\nu(X) = \lambda\left(X\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\right)$, where $\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}$ is a random variable i.e., $\nu(\omega) = \lambda(\omega)\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(\omega)$, all $\omega\in\Omega$. Show that 
>   $$E\nu[X|\mathcal{F_t}] = \frac{E_{\lambda}\left[X\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}|\mathcal{F_t}\right]}{E_{\lambda}\left[\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}|\mathcal{F}_t\right]}$$

Recall from the second fundamental theorem of asset pricing $$\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} = \frac{S_T^{0}}{\lambda(S_T^{0})}$$ if $S_T^{0}$ is a constant then $$\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda} = 1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \lambda = \nu$$ 
The change of measure formula is $$E_{\nu}[X] = E_{\lambda}\left[X\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right]$$

For some attainable claim $X$ let $\phi$ be a self financing strategy replicating $X$ then by the first fundamental theorem of asset pricing $$V_t(\phi) = E_{\nu}\left[X\frac{S_t^{0}}{S_T^{0}} |\mathcal{F_t}\right]$$

I am pretty sure the result will follow from one of these fundamental theorems of asset pricing but I am not sure where to go from here. Sorry for the messy start, also if you need me to write the three fundamental theorems I would be happy to do so. Any comments or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Alternative Solution - For all $\omega\in \Omega$, let $\mathcal{F}_t(\omega) = \mathcal{F}_t$ be the partition element containing $\omega$. Then

\begin{align*}
E_{\nu}[X|\mathcal{F}_t](\omega) &= \frac{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} X(\omega)\nu(\omega)}{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} \nu(\omega)}\\
&= \frac{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} X(\omega)\lambda(\omega)\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(\omega)}{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)}\lambda(\omega)\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(\omega)}\\
&= \frac{\left(
\frac{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} X(\omega)\lambda(\omega)\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(\omega)}{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} \lambda(\omega)} \right )}{\left(\frac{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} \lambda(\omega)\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}(\omega)}{\sum_{\omega\in\mathcal{F}_t(\omega)} \lambda(\omega)} \right )}\\
&= \frac{E_{\lambda}\left[X\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}|\mathcal{F}_t\right](\omega)}{E_{\lambda}\left[\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}|\mathcal{F}_t\right](\omega)}
\end{align*}

Comment: If $\lambda$ and $\nu$ are measures, then $\lambda(\omega)$ and $\nu(\omega)$ do not make good sense. What do you mean $\lambda(S_T^0)$? Is $S_t^0$ a numeraire process?

Comment: @Gordon I may have written the question down wrongly I will double check. $S_t^{0}$ is a numeraire process. Apologies if I made some notation mistake, I will correct it.

Comment: @Gordon in regards to the $\lambda(S_T^{0})$ question, it is just a normalization factor to ensure that $\nu$ has total mass $1$. We define $\nu$ by means of the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506965/change-of-measure-of-conditional-expectation).

Comment: @Gordon posted the solution but the latex generator here is messed up

Comment: Corrected your latex errors. I do not think your solution makes sense, as $\mathcal{F}_t$ is a $\sigma$-filed, how can you take the sum on elements of it, and the elements are not the samples, they are events.

Comment: I wrote out this exact solution in class today and my professor said it was correct.

Comment: Then, I will have some doubts for the professor.

Comment: @Gordon Perhaps, although no student said it was wrong as well and I saw that some students did basically the same thing as I did. Not sure I can double check with the professor again

Comment: The notation $\omega \in \mathcal{F}_t(\omega)$ does not make sense to me. Note that $\mathcal{F}_t$ consists of events, which may be uncountable. Then how can you take a sum on them? It is better to make it crystal clear and let you professor know. Otherwise, how can you write your PhD thesis later on?

Comment: I'll talk to my professor then edit this solution, good point.

Comment: For finite sample space, your proof may be fine. I was talking for general sample space.

Comment: Oh I see yes we assumed that we are working in a finite sample space otherwise I think we would use the approach you did in the link you posted

Comment: @Gordon do you know how to prove this? http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30843/law-of-one-price-and-the-inconcistent-pricing-strategy

Comment: I am not familiar with that. Basically, these topics may be good for academic purpose. In practice, we do not use them at all. But I will think about it. What is the reference book for it?

Comment: ok thank you, ill re-edit if I think of anything else

Comment: What is the textbook you are using.

Comment: This book in particular is called Lectures on Financial Mathematics: Discrete Asset Pricing. I can send you the pdf if you want

Comment: Is it by Greg Anderson and Alec N. Kercheval? I have that book.

Comment: Yes thats the one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let define $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ two equivalent probabilities on a filtered space $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0})$

Let define $Z_T=\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}$ restricted to $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable events.

It means that for $X_T$ being $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable we have:
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X_T] = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[Z_TX_T\right]$$

---

Let $t\leq T$.

We want to define the change of probability measure on $\mathcal{F}_t$.
i.e we want to find $Z_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable such that for $X_t$ being $\mathbb{F}_t$ measurable, we have:

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X_t]= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[Z_tX_t\right]$$

By definition of $Z_T$, and since $X_t$ is also $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[X_t]= \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}\left[Z_TX_t\right]$$

i.e

for any $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable we have $Z_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable such that:

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_T X_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_t X_t]$$

so $Z_t = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$ by definition of conditional expectation.

---

Let $Y_T$ being $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable, then we want to compute $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$.

We denote $Y_t = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_T|\mathcal{F}_t]$

We look for $Y_t$ such that for any $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable, we have :

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_TX_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_t X_t]$$

By definition of $Z_T$ we have $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_TX_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_TY_TX_t]$

By definition of $Z_t$ we have $\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_tX_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_tY_tX_t]$

so we have:

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_TY_TX_t]=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_tY_tX_t]$$

and again by definition of conditional expectation, we have:

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_TY_T|\mathcal{F}_t]=Z_tY_t$$

we can now conclude using the definition of $Y_t$ and $Z_t$.

$$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}[Y_T|\mathcal{F}_t] = \frac{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_TY_T|\mathcal{F}_t]}{\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{P}}[Z_T|\mathcal{F}_t]}$$

Comment: Very good, indeed.

Comment: I wish this was clear for me haha